# EmptyStackException for non empty stack

Tags: java, exception, stack

How do I handle `EmptyStackException` for this block of code? Shows my stack is empty after reading some part of the file. I'm guessing it has to do with the `push()` and `pop()` methods but not sure completely.

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    int op1, op2, result = 0;
    String token;
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(expr);

    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        token = tokenizer.nextToken();
        char c = token.charAt(0);
        if (isOperator(c)) {
            op2 = ((Integer) stack.pop()).intValue();
            op1 = ((Integer) stack.pop()).intValue();
            result = evalSingleOp(token.charAt(0), op1, op2);
            stack.push(new Integer(result));

        } else {
            stack.push(new Integer(Integer.parseInt(token)));

        }

    }

    result = ((Integer) stack.pop()).intValue();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: "Says my stack is empty when it isn't." So you're calling the Java runtime a liar? Of course it has to do with `push()` and `pop()`. Those are the only things that manipulate the stack. Either you're getting bad input, or you have a logic error. Show some more effort.

Comment: It's simple.  You start with an empty stack, then the program skips over the while loop because there aren't any tokens in the input, then you try to pop the stack but there's nothing there.  If there really are tokens in the input, **why are you hiding them from us???**

Comment: Also, where does the exception occur? You didn't show the stacktrace, which is the most important thing to show when you get an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is arising due to the following lines of code.

```
op2 = ((Integer) stack.pop()).intValue();
op1 = ((Integer) stack.pop()).intValue();
```

During the first iteration of the loop if the first character of the *'expr'* is an operator then the condition inside if becomes true

```
if (isOperator(c)) //true
```

But since it is the first iteration, stack does not have any operands in it to pop.

The above code works fine for *'expr'* such as **1 2 +** having enough operands before the operators, but not for *'expr'* such as **+ 1 2** which does not have enough(2) operands before an operator.

Answer (score -1):

I guess, you should check `stack.length` before `stack.pop()`

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment (or is it an answer? if it is, it's wrong and bad).